# How to plot a 3d histogram from 3 different lists (x, y and z), where z is the mean of all repeated x,y coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, histogram

I wanna plot a 3D histogram with matplotlib, from three list that look like:

```
x = [random.randint(0, 12) for i in range(101)]  
y = [random.randint(0, 12) for i in range(101)]  
z = [random.random() for i in range(101)]
```

the point is that the x and y axes must range from 0 to 12, and each (x,y) bin must represent the mean value for all the z values that meet each (x,y) criteria. For instance, let's imagine that

```
x[0] = 5  
y[0] = 3  
z[0] = 0.8
```

could happens that:

```
x[25] = 5  
y[25] = 3  
z[25] = 0.6
```

so the histogram must put a 0.7 heigh bin (the mean of all the instances where x = 5 AND y = 3) on coordinates (x,y) = (5,3).

Does somebody has an idea about how to do it pythonically?

Best and thanks a lot!
Mauricio.

Answer (score 1):

take a look on this:

```
import numpy as np
n=101

x = [np.random.randint(0, 12) for i in range(n)]  
y = [np.random.randint(0, 12) for i in range(n)]  
z = [np.random.random() for i in range(n)]

#coord=[(x[i],y[i]) for i in range(n)]

m=np.asarray([x,y]).transpose()

d=dict()
for i in range(n):
    coord=tuple(m[i])
    d[coord]=d[coord]+[z[i]] if coord in d else [z[i]]    

#for e in d:
#    print e,np.asarray(d[e]).mean()

m2=[]
for e in d:
    m2.append([list(e)[0],list(e)[1],np.asarray(d[e]).mean()])

m2=np.asarray(m2).transpose()
```

First, it saves in m the coordinates by transposing x and y arrays.

Then, it creates a dictionary to store the list of z values for each unique coordinate.

Finally, it stores in m2 the mean values for each coordinate, where 'x'=m2[0], 'y'=m2[1] and 'z-mean'=m2[2]

I think there should be better solutions,
Hope this helps.